# N900 Wi-Fi card that works with an N300 router

Tags: networking

Been using a USB dongle nano on a Debian machine. It is spotty.Want a  PCIe card instead.

what is the best  pCI express card for  TL-WR841N router. would prefer a high end card in case of getting a higher rated router in the future

Comment: This question will be closed so long as it is about whether or not this card can connect to your router; that's a technical support question. Reword it so that it is about what internal wifi card using a PCIe connector would be the *best* choice given your router.